# Visual Studio hotkey detection on run

Tags: visual-studio, hotkeys, compiler-directives

Weird one maybe. Is there anyway to detect a hotkey combo at run-time after firing up the project in VS.

E.g. If I hold shift and press f5 or run in VS then i want to fire a special line of code.

If you don't press the hotkey combo then it fires as normal.

Answer (score 0):

*(You tagged your question with 'visual studio'; I assume Windows OS)*

Shift case:

```
if(::GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT) < 0) // Shift down
{
    // Do something ("special line of code") only if Shift down
}
```

Caps Lock case:

```
SHORT nState = ::GetAsyncKeyState(VK_CAPITAL); // Caps Lock
bool bToggled = nState & 1;
bool bDown = nState & 0x8000;

if (bToggled)
{
    // Do something ("special line of code") only if Caps Lock toggled 
}
```

*...place it in main(), for instance*

--

Ref.: [GetAsyncKeyState()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate)